# Select Tab on Button Click

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

I have create a tabcontrol in Silverlight 4 with four tabs, is possible open a tab with button?

this cose is only windows forms

```
tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage4;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `TabControl.SelectedIndex` property to change the selected tab from code.

For example, when you want to select the third tab:

```
tabControlName.SelectedIndex = 2;
```

Comment: The third tab should be selected if the index is set to 2. Make sure you are not testing with the third one already selected. If still doesn't work - provide more code in question for deeper analysis.

Comment: thanks so much..the tab index is incorrect..i have correct and work

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the: [TabControl Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

surely you can use one of these two properties:

> SelectedIndex - Gets or **sets** the index of the currently selected TabItem
>
> SelectedItem - Gets or **sets** the currently selected TabItem.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Source: Youtube</sub>
[C# Tabpage Select with button, 3 way.](https://youtu.be/yPrCVdJp-II)

```
    private void btnPage1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button ;

        // method 1
        if(button==button1)
            tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        else if(button==button2)
            tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;
        else // if(button==button3)
            tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 2;

        // method 2
        if(button==button1)
            tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages["tabPage1"];
        else if(button==button2)
            tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages["tabPage2"];
        else // if(button==button3)
            tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages["tabPage3"];

        // method 3
        // button Name : btnPage1, btnPage2, btnPage3
        // tabPage Name : tabPage1, tabPage2, tabPage3
        string tabName = button.Name.Replace("btn", "tab") ;
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages[tabName] ;
    }
```